# Total Internal reflection and law of reflection

Tags: reflection, refraction

Does the 2nd law of reflection (i.e angle of incidence equal to angle of reflection) holds for total internal reflection?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in fact both the laws of reflection hold true for total internal reflection.